# Cannot update React-native

Tags: android, npm, react-native

After using react-native upgrade, as suggested in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/upgrading I got:

> info No version passed. Fetching latest...
>   info Fetching diff between v0.59.10 and v0.61.2...
>   error Failed to fetch diff for react-native@0.61.2. Maybe it's not released yet?
>   info For available releases to diff see: https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge#version-changes

Changing to a specific version (react-native upgrade 0.61.0-rc.0) do not help.

Enviroment:

```
react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.10

npm -v 6.12.0

node -v v10.16.0
```

system: windows 10

Comment: It seems like the error you've got shouldn't happen. Can you please submit issue to https://github.com/react-native-community/cli and provide more details on the error?

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading **react-native** can be very painful. The complexity of the upgrade depends on:

- What version of RN you are trying to upgrade
- How many native dependencies your project has
- How many custom *things* your project has

**0.59.x** to **0.60.x** could be painful because many new things were introduced like: auto-linking, hermes and a lot of components were moved from core react-native repo to community repositories in the lean-core effort (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23313).

## react-native upgrade

**react-native upgrade** is a somewhat primitive command (it tries to apply git diff to your project native files) and in most cases, it just won't work - at least it never worked for me.

## Upgrading

In my case, I like to start with reading [release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases). After doing that, I usually check what was changed in Android/iOS project files. There is a really helpful community tool - https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/. I try to manually apply those changes to my project, but usually, I need to adjust a lot of project-specific things like upgrading native dependencies and adjusting build tools. Soon, you will be able to ask for help or find common issues with upgrading in new community repository - https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support.